# Multiple input file in one form

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, upload

I have form :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="edit_kategori.php">
     <input type="file" name="icon-main" id="icon-main">
     <input type="file" name="icon-hover" id="icon-hover">
<form>
```

I want to upload two images from two input files, but only the last one file I have choosen that uploaded. and here is my php:

```
$dirMain = $_FILES['icon-main']['tmp_name'];
$dirHover = $_FILES['icon-hover']['tmp_name'];

//main icon
$tempMain = explode(".", $_FILES['icon-main']['name']);
$newMain = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($tempMain);

$iconMain = $folder . basename($newMain);   

//hover icon
$tempHover = explode(".", $_FILES['icon-hover']['name']);
$newHover = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($tempHover);

$iconHover = $folder . basename($newHover); 

if (!empty($dirMain)&&!empty($dirHover)) {
        $dir[] = $dirMain;
        $dir[] = $dirHover;

        $icon[] = $iconMain;
        $icon[] = $iconHover;

        for ($i=0; $i <= 1; $i++) { 
            move_uploaded_file($dir[$i] , $icon[$i]);
        }

    }
```

Is that because "tmp_name" can only store one file ? Thanks for helping :)

Comment: it might be useful to `vardump` each part so you will know which part is not working properly

Comment: you can try to get the return value form `move_uploaded_file` to determine if the action is successful or not

Answer (score 0):

Just small mistake, loop through `<= 1`

```
for ($i=0; $i <= 1; $i++) { 
            move_uploaded_file($dir[$i] , $icon[$i]);
        }
```

I guess storing `$_FILES['yourvar']['tmp_name']` is causing issue. I have tried this both ways and it might useful to you the difference:

**Method 1: (working)**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['icon-main']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['icon-main']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['icon-hover']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['icon-hover']['name']);
```

**Method 2: (not working)**

```
$d = $_FILES['icon-main']['tmp_name'];
$k = $_FILES['icon-hover']['tmp_name'];
move_uploaded_file($d, $_FILES['icon-main']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($k, $_FILES['icon-hover']['name']);
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I've changed <=1, but It did'nt work, only the last file could be uploaded...

Answer (score 0):

I just find the way, I move file manualy using if, not looping...

```
$target = "../category/";
$dir = $target . basename( $_FILES['icon-main']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['icon-main']['tmp_name'], $dir)) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $dir;
}   else {
    echo "Fail";
};


$dir = $target . basename( $_FILES['icon-hover']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['icon-hover']['tmp_name'], $dir)) {

    echo "<br>";
    echo $dir;
} else {
    echo "Fail";
};
```